# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Not supported (Screensharing Using The WebRTC)

Tags: javascript, electron, webrtc, mozilla, mac-catalyst

I have electronjs app for the MAC Catalyst. I have implemented audio/video calling functionalities. Those works well.

I have also implemented functionality to share the screen by using below code.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(options).then((streams) => {
    var peer_connection = session.sessionDescriptionHandler.peerConnection;
    var video_track = streams.getVideoTracks()[0];
    var sender_kind = peer_connection.getSenders().find((sender) => {
        return sender.track.kind == video_track.kind;
    });
    sender_kind.replaceTrack(video_track);

    video_track.onended = () => {
    };
},
    () => {
        console.log("Error occurred while sharing screen");
    }
);
```

But when I hit the button to share the screen by using above code, I am getting below error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Not supported
```

I have also tried `navigator.getUserMedia(options,success,error)`. It's supported by the Mac Catalyst desktop apps. But it's only giving the streams of the webcam.

I have also checked online if `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(options)` is supported in the Mac Catalyst or not. It's supports in the Mac Catalyst. But still I am facing this issue.

I have also tried with the `desktopCapturer` API of the electronjs. But I don't know how can I get the streams from it.

```
//CODE OF 'main.js'

ipcMain.on("ask_permission", () => {
  desktopCapturer
    .getSources({ types: ["window", "screen"] })
    .then(async (sources) => {
      for (const source of sources) {
        // console.log(source);
        if (source.name === "Entire screen") {
          win.webContents.send("SET_SOURCE", source.id);
          return;
        }
      }
    });
});
```

I have tried to get streams by using the below code in the **preload.js**. But I was getting the error `Cannot read property 'srcObject' of undefined`.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  ipcRenderer.on("SET_SOURCE", async (event, sourceId) => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
            chromeMediaSourceId: sourceId,
            minWidth: 1280,
            maxWidth: 1280,
            minHeight: 720,
            maxHeight: 720,
          },
        },
      });
      handleStream(stream);
    } catch (e) {
      handleError(e);
    }
  });
  let btn = document.getElementById("btnStartShareOutgoingScreens");
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (isSharing == false) {
      ipcRenderer.send("ask_permission");
    } else {
      console.error("USer is already sharing the screen..............");
    }
  });
});

function handleStream(stream) {
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.muted = true;
  video.id = "screenShareVideo";
  video.style.display = "none";
  const box = document.getElementById("app");
  box.appendChild(video);
  isSharing = true;
}
```

How can I resolve it. If this is not supported in the MAC Catalyst, Is there is any other way to share the screen from the MAC Catalyst app by using WebRTC.